# Jquery .css() sending full path in background

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, background

Hi I'm adding a background image through jQuery, but in chrome, when I do `.css("background", "url(foo/bar.jpg)")` it adds the full path like `http://localhost/project/foo/bar.jpg`. Anyone knows about this issue?

Here's the actual code I'm using:

```
$("#"+id, opener.window.document).css("background", "url(<?=$folder?>/"+arquivo+")"+bgattr);
```

It's a popup that changes the opener background.

In Firefox it adds just the relative path, as it was supposed to. Just tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: That depends how css property is parsed specifically by browser. So what's wrong with absolute path? Why do you need it to *'stay'* relative? Sounds like a XY problem

Comment: How are you getting `bgattr` (or is that `arquivo`?)?  bgattr is outside the ")".  Check/parse it then and not worry about it.  What if the background image *is* a full path (ie is hosted on a different site) - FF would also return a full path.

Comment: `bgattr` is the rest of the arguments: `center center no-repeat`, it's adding correctly. And I need it to stay relative because I process the styles after the addition, and the full path is braking my code. As I'm adding the relative path, I was expecting a relative path to be added, not a full...